# Css doesn't work for elements inserted by innerHTML

Tags: reactjs

So I want to add an image in componentDidMount like this:

```
document.getElementById('d3_16').innerHTML = `<img src=${damsel} 
className="npcSprite" />`
```

Everything shows up correctly, class in inspector seems to be assigned however the styles dont apply, while other elements created normally have their styles loaded properly.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Use `class` instead of `className` since it just plain HTML and not JSX

Comment: When you change the HTML manually, you need to take care of the full lifecycle of that DOM element. Can you share your relevant component code?

Comment: @TryingToImprove  You're absolutely right, that fixed the problem, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should use `class` instead of `className` since it is just plain HTML and not JSX.

Comment: Simple solution ! wasted an hour figuring out.